# Transitioning volley's NetworkImageView to another activity does not show up

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, transition

I'm working on a simple app that has a ListView with a NetworkImageView in it. When the user taps on a row in the ListView, I would like to transition the NetworkImageView to a different activity.

I followed this source: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

The problem is that the NetworkImageView is missing in the activity I'm transitioning to. Could anyone point me in the right direction, because I have no clue what I am missing.

**Step 1: Enable Window Content Transitions**

style.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- enable window content transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

**Step 2: Assign a Common Transition Name**

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp" >

<!-- Thumbnail Image -->
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:transitionName="thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

<!-- Movie Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<!-- Genre -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/genre"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textColor="@color/genre"
    android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_detail_event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<!-- Thumbnail Image -->
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/cover"
    android:transitionName="thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 3: Start Activity**

MainActivity.java

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final View thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailEventActivity.class);

        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, thumbnail, "thumbnail");
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }
});
```